# canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) function in UITextView does not recognize 'replace(_:)' action

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, selector, uiresponder

I need to configure my UITextView such that it only performs a select set of actions via the Edit menu. I tried to override the 'canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?)' function to achieve this.

```
class NewTextView: UITextView {

override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(paste(_:)) || action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(cut(_:)) || action == #selector(select(_:)) || action == #selector(selectAll(_:))
    {
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
    return false
}
```

}

But when I tried to check for the 'replace(_:)' selector, I got the following error. which says "Cannot find 'replace' in scope".
[error screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpKIo.png)

Right now I have handled it by checking for its description, but I'm not sure how robust this method is.

```
if action.description == "replace:"
{
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `replace` selector in the Standard Edit Actions so it cannot work anyway.

The `action.description` check is fine but if you want to check the selector directly outside of a class conforming to `UIView` you have to specify the type where the selector is declared, for example `paste`

```
if action == #selector(UIResponder.paste(_:))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The replace function is declared in the UITextInput protocol. Since it is not declared as an optional function I could not check for its selector.

Comment: I see. But the proper signature is `#selector(UITextInput.replace(_:withText:))`